# Handlebars Switching Context to a property of the context using if/else

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Just wonderdering what the best way to handle the following situation is.

*Using : Ember 1.7.0, Handlebars 1.3.0*

Context:

```
var context = {
    isPerson : true,

    person : {
        name : 'joe'
    },
    animal : {
        name : 'henry'
    }
};
```

HBS:

```
{{#if isPerson}}
    {{#with person}}
{{else}}
    {{#with animal}}
{{/if}}

{{name}}

{{/with}}
```

The context is a dummy context, the real context is quite a large data set with many properties. What I am trying to achieve is to reduce the amount of handlebars needed to implement this. I know that I can simply just do the following...

```
{{#if isPerson}}
    {{#with person}}
        {{name}}
    {{/with}}
{{else}}
    {{#with animal}}
        {{name}}
    {{/with}}
{{/if}}
```

The problem here is that I will be rendering around 100 fields. Both the "person" and "animal" objects have identical keys, In this case it would be best to reduce the handlebars needed in favor of switching the context to one of the inner keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is with a computed property that resolves to either the person or animal object. Let's call it `creature` for the sake of the example.

```
creature: function() {
    if (this.get('context.isPerson')) {
        return this.get('context.person');
    } else {
        return this.get('context.animal');
    }
}.property('context.isPerson')
```

Then in your template, just use the `creature` property:

```
{{#with creature}}
    {{name}}
{{/with}}
```